# Does mobile safari use UIWebView class?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I have error in a phonegap application and in my website when I open it in chrome browser in IOS. I suspect that it happens because of chrome and phonegap use UIWebView class. But there is no errors in mobile safari. So, I would like to know if safari use this class too.

Answer (score 2):

No. Chrome does indeed contain a UIWebView, but most of MobileSafari is built on WebKit.